# Excel Formula - Yeah thats right, I said excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If `A1` contains 0.3 I want `B1` to say 1

If `A1` says0.45 I want `B1` to say 0

If it's anything in-between 0.3 and 0.45 I want it to say the proportional difference, so if `A1` said 0.375, `B1` should say 0.5 as its half way between 0.3 and 0.45.

Is is even possible? I'm thinking nested `IF`s but I can't see how to actually get there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could try this: `=(0.45-A1)/(0.45-0.3)`

Simplified: `=(0.45-A1)/0.15`

Another alternative: `=3-A1/0.15`

Comment: Sheer genious! I don't think it can be simplified further :D

Comment: this is fine for the examples you have provided, but it is unbounded. Your examples cater for A1 being between 0.3 and .45, if its possible for A1 to lie outside this range then joshb's solution is more suited.

Comment: @brettdj The original poster did not specify the behavior for values outside the range 0.3 to 0.45, so I did not address that.  It may be that the message "out of range" is desired in that case, but it may also be that the result of the given formula is the appropriate value.  Or it may be something else entirely.

Comment: @phoog. That's all correct. But still I'd rather see basic boundary handling as per joshb's approach, his answer covers the question concisely but it also makes it very clear how to address a value outside the specified range. So the OP could easily adjust it rather than have to ask a further clarifying question.

Answer (score 3):

`=IF(AND(A1 >= 0.3, A1 <= 0.45), ((0.45-A1)/(0.45-0.3)), "out of range")`

Comment: +1 for considering the (unspecified) case where the value is not between 0.3 and 0.45.

Comment: Oh yes, that is a good idea (although the interface controls wouldn't let this happen which I didn't mention, this is still very important though so thanks!).

Answer (score 2):

This?
`=IF(A1=0.3,1,IF(A1=0.45,0,((0.45-A1)/0.15)))`

Comment: The IF functions aren't necessary.  It's a bit like saying `=IF(C3=1,1,IF(C3=2,2,C3))`.

Comment: You are quite correct. I really like your answer and +1'd it.

Answer (score 1):

this seem to work and looks easy.In B1
`=(0.45-A1/0.15)+2.55`